# How to configure rails app (especially routing) hosted on heroku to run via an nginx proxy which uses a subdirectory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, heroku, hosting, subdirectory

I have a rails application hosted on heroku with a url like `exampleapp.herokuapp.com`. My company requires it to be served such that `companydomain.com/exampleapp` will point to that heroku instance.

The configuration is as follows

In `config/application.rb`:

`config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/exampleapp"`

In `config/environements/*.rb`

`config.assets.prefix = /exampleapp/assets`

And for the routes, I have scoped them to an optional parameter like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   scope '(:prefix)' do
      # routes
   end
end
```

And in `application_controller.rb`

```
def default_url_options
    {prefix:  'exampleapp'}
end
```

This will make the application available in both prefixed and unprefixed url. For example: `/login` and `/exampleapp/login` will both work just fine and any other prefix will as well.

I guess it wouldn't matter eitherway. But I want to know if this is a correct way to go about this?

**Rails Version**: `6.1.4`
**Ruby Version**: `2.7.2`